# How can I get the underlying link with Data factory web scraper

Tags: azure, web-scraping, azure-data-factory

I have made in Azure Data Factory a very simple pipeline which reads a table from a web page.

However one of the columns contains links. Thus, Data Factory returns the visible text but not the link associated with that text. Is it possible to configure the web scraper to return the links? Or do I need a more sophisticated framework like Selenium?

My source dataset is this

```
{
"name": "SourceDataset_n4m",
"properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "PlayersTable",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "WebTable",
    "schema": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "index": 1
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At this time, it is not possible using Web Table connector in ADF. I would recommend submitting a feature request in Azure data factory feedback forum here - https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c